# Resolve NetBIOS names without full qualification

Tags: linux-networking, netbios, winbind

I am connected to my office VPN and I can successfully RDP into my computer using the fully qualified name for it PC00001.myofficevpn.plc.

When I try to connect using only the hostname PC00001, I do not get access, is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added `search myofficevpn.plc` to my `/etc/resolv.conf` file and it worked.